# How can i use ationbarSherlock if my activity already extends from another activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an acitivity that extends from another activity, and now i want add actionbar to it. But in the useage page http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html i found that my activity must extends from **SherlockXXX** activity, which confuse me a lot. Since java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, i cannot meet that requriment. My question is, is there another way to use actionbar instead of  extending from Sherlock activity, like implementing some interfaces, or wrap it within acitvity? And if not, what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

> I have an acitivity that extends from another activity

Make that **another activity** extend `SherlockActivity` instead of normal `Activity`.